# Hex Editing in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, hex, hex-editors

I want to edit a hex location (for eg.0x90F10-0x90F15) in a DLL file.

Is there any library or APIs by which I can do it in .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Call `File.OpenWrite` to get a `FileStream` for your file
2. Set `Stream.Position` to jump to the location you want to edit
3. Call `Stream.Write` to overwrite bytes in the file.

Comment: Are you sure that `Stream.Write` is going to work after you've called `File.OpenRead`? I suspect you'll need instead to call the `FileStream` constructor and give it a `FileAccess` of `ReadWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide much detail or source only a general pointer:

Try [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) - you can read and write any byte/byte array...