# Editing hex of code of an application

Tags: vb.net, binary, hex, visual-studio-2010

I have recently seen few application where I can edit certain blocks of hex by giving the valid offset.

The question is, how do they do that? Are there any function which allow binary string editing in vb.net?

There is no much about that on google, so could you tell me how can I edit the application source in vb.net like in the hex editor?

Comment: check next project from sourceforge "Be.HexEditor (.NET C# hex edit control)" http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hex Editing in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474904/hex-editing-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474956/864101):

> 1. Call `File.OpenWrite` to get a `FileStream` for your file
> 2. Set `Stream.Position` to jump to the location you want to edit
> 3. Call `Stream.Write` to overwrite bytes in the file.